# How would I simulate a Javascript require so that I can inline the code I want rather than reference another file that contains it?

Tags: javascript, require, iife

Here's how we would normally just `require` a file:

```
var littleLisp = require("./littlelisp").littleLisp;
// then use it:
var ret = littleLisp.interpret(...);  // etc.
```

But I want to inline the code rather than using `require`.

The actual file I want to inline is this one:  https://github.com/maryrosecook/littlelisp/blob/master/littlelisp.js

Abbreviated, it looks like this, an IIFE:

```
;(function(exports) {
  // library, Context, special, interpretList,interpret, categorize, parenthesize, tokenize, parse
  var library = {
    ...
  };
  var interpret = function(input, context) {
    ...
  };
  .
  .
  .
  var parse = function(input) {
    ...
  };
  exports.littleLisp = {
    parse: parse,
    interpret: interpret
  };
})(typeof exports === 'undefined' ? this : exports);
```

What I would like is some version of that IIFE copied into my source so I don't have to hit the net:

```
<head>
<source>
// some manipulation of the above IIFE
var littleLisp = modified_IIFE.littleLisp;
// then use it:
var ret = littleLisp.interpret(...);  // etc.
</source>
</head>
```

(Notice that I'm in HTML-land).  How can I hand-modify and then inline the desired code so that the above will work?

Comment: Change the `exports.littleLisp = ` to `return`, and remove the `exports` parameters?

Comment: Perfect!  That worked.  I figured it had to be simple.  Thanks!